# Trying to Create Basic API with before_action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First time trying to create an API and am having some issues. I want to use the Host header in the post request to find the property that the lead is supposed to be routed to. However I get undefined local variable or method for my method that is supposed to pull the header out and find the correct property. Here is the controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
before_action capture_header, only: :create
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

def create
  @property.leads.create!(lead_params)
end


private

def lead_params
  params.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :moveindate, :source)
end

def capture_header
  referrer = request.headers["HTTP_REFERER"]
  domain = URI.parse(referrer).host.match(/\w*.com$/)[0]
  @property = Property.where(url: domain)
end

end
```

The error:

> undefined local variable or method `capture_header' for
>   LeadsController:Class

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `before_action :capture_header, only: :create`

Comment: thank you, this worked. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing symbol for method "capture_header".
Please try: `before_action :capture_header, only: :create`

Comment: that's what I commented 20 minutes before :)